# Images and Favicons in Yii2

Tags: html, yii2, yii2-basic-app

Using Yii2 at the moment and looking how to place a company logo in the header of the Yii2 basic application, and where I should store images in the Yii2 application hierarchy as well. As well as how to change the favicon of that specific application.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Yii2 basic application template the default favicon in placed in basic/web directory. for company image the simplest way is place them in the same directory although the most appropriate way is to use the assets

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, when you say assets, you are talking about the assets directory right? How would you give the path or call this image using Yii2 notation?